# for each loop is reading the array wrong

Tags: c++, c

I know i am better then this.

But each time i run the array instead of starting at 1 to 5 it starts at 49. I don't know why but this is starting to get annoying.

I am sure this is simple but i don't see how right now. 
What i want to do is run the foreach loop and print out that part of the array.
Then i want to test the Status[].

The status should only print the test number when the conditions are right. 
testnum = arr[i]

```
int main(void)
{ 
    char status[10];
    int test1 = 0, test2 = 0, test3 = 0, test4 = 0;
    int arr[] = {'1','2','3','4','5'}; 
    int value[] = { '1','2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25'};




    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf(" \n %i#  %i \n", i, arr[i]);


    }

    printf("test S:  %i \n", test1);
    printf("test MS: %i \n", test2);
    printf("test MJ: %i \n", test3);
    printf("test SH: %i \n", test4);

    system("pause");

}
```

UPDATE: sorry meant to say i reads it wrong. Instead of reading and writing 1 2 3 4 5 it says 49 50 and so on

Comment: how are you guys so fast to view this?

Comment: The main question list view pushes notifications to the browser when there are new questions.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the character `'1'` appears to be 49 on your system. The numeral characters are contiguous an in any encoding which explains the 50, etc.

Perhaps you meant: `int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: @user3255517: I say that in the second paragraph.

Comment: I like the hyper-neutral "on your system," as if OP might be using an EBCDIC computer. `'1'` is codepoint 49 in any modern encoding you can imagine. :)

Comment: @StilesCrisis: Why should I burden the answer with such specific detail, though? The actual value isn't important, what matters is that `'1'` is a character literal with an implementation-defined value.

Answer (score 1):

```
int arr[] = {'1','2','3','4','5'};
```

Characters surrounded by single quotes (`'`) are character literals. Their value is the value of that character in your execution character set, which is likely some ASCII compatible character set. In ASCII, the character `'1'` has value 49. Take a look at [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Instead, you want to initialise your arrays like this:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

These are now integer literals and have the value you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

'1' is not the same as 1.

'1' is the character 1, just like 'a' is the character a. When used as a number, it's equivalent to its ASCII code 49. If you print it as a number, you get 49. Mathematical operations are usually meaningless on it. If you double it, you get 'b' (ASCII code 98).

1 is the actual number 1. If you print it as a number, you get 1. If you double it, you get 2.